# Exact rules for matching variadic template template parameters in partial template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, partial-specialization, template-templates

While creating [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72911415/17862371) answer for another question I came around the following issue. Consider this program ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n6YofTzGr)):

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct TypeChecker {
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "I am other type\n";
    }
};

template<typename... Ts, template<typename...> typename V>
requires std::same_as<V<Ts...>, std::variant<Ts...>>
struct TypeChecker<V<Ts...>>
{
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "I am std::variant\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    TypeChecker<std::variant<int, float>>{}();
    TypeChecker<int>{}();
}
```

The output (which is also expected) is the following (with clang 14.0.0 as well as with gcc 12.1):

```
I am std::variant
I am other type
```

If however the three dots in the parameter list of the template template are removed, like this (whole program live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5fTannrza)):

```
template<typename... Ts, template<typename> typename V>
```

,then the output is different for clang and gcc. The clang 14.0.0 compiled program outputs

```
I am other type
I am other type
```

whereas the gcc 12.1 compiled program outputs

```
I am std::variant
I am other type
```

It seems that using the non-variadic template template exhibits different matching rules in clang and gcc. So my question is, which behavior is correct if it is even well defined, and why?

Comment: Very likely one of them has additional template parameters in `std::variant<>` with default values.

Comment: @lorro the behavior is the same even if I do not use `std::variant` at all but any other variadic template like e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qc7nPbYbf)

Comment: Shouldn't this report an error that `V` accepts one type only?

Comment: MSVC agrees with gcc https://godbolt.org/z/WGno667fq

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691007/compiler-discrepancy-with-simple-meta-function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since defect report resolution [P0522R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html) was adopted, exact matching of template parameter lists for template template parameter match is no longer needed, and correct output according to the standard is:

```
I am std::variant
I am other type
```

In the current draft (which also contains changes related to C++20 concepts) relevant standard excerpts are [temp.arg.template#3-4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.arg.template#3) (bold emphasis mine):

> 3. A *template-argument* matches a template *template-parameter* P when P **is at least as specialized as** the *template-argument* A. In this comparison, if P is unconstrained, the constraints on A are not considered. **If P contains a template parameter pack, then A also matches P if each of A's template parameters matches the corresponding template parameter** in the *template-head* of P. Two template parameters match if they are of the same kind (type, non-type, template), for non-type *template-parameter*s, their types are equivalent ([temp.over.link]), and for template *template-parameter*s, each of their corresponding *template-parameter*s matches, recursively. When P's *template-head* contains a template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]), the template parameter pack will match zero or more template parameters or template parameter packs in the *template-head* of A with the same type and form as the template parameter pack in P (ignoring whether those template parameters are template parameter packs).
> 4. A template *template-parameter* P **is at least as specialized as** a template *template-argument* A if, given the following rewrite to two function templates, the function template corresponding to P is at least as specialized as the function template corresponding to A **according to the partial ordering rules for function templates**. Given an invented class template X with the *template-head* of A (including default arguments and *requires-clause*, if any):
>
>    - (4.1) Each of the two function templates has the same template parameters and *requires-clause* (if any), respectively, as P or A.
>    - (4.2) Each function template has a single function parameter whose type is a specialization of X with template arguments corresponding to the template parameters from the respective function template where, for each template parameter PP in the *template-head* of the function template, a corresponding template argument AA is formed. If PP declares a template parameter pack, then AA is the pack expansion PP... ([temp.variadic]); otherwise, AA is the *id-expression* PP.
>      If the rewrite produces an invalid type, then P is not at least as specialized as A.

So, as we see, exact (up to special rules for parameter pack) parameter matching is now considered only in the case parameter list of template template parameter contains a pack (like your original example), otherwise only the new *at least as specialized as* relation is used to test matching, which defines for both template template parameter and argument respective function templates and tests whether parameter-induced function is *at least as specialized as* argument-induced function according to partial ordering rules for template functions.

In particular, matching A=`std::variant` to P=`template<typename> typename V` we get these corresponding function templates:

```
template<typename...> class X;
template<typename T> void f(X<T>); // for P
template<typename... Ts> void f(X<Ts...>); // for A
```

So, to prove A matches P, we need to prove `f(X<T>)` is at least as specialized as `f(X<Ts...>)`. [temp.func.order#2-4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.func.order#2) says:

> 2. Partial ordering selects which of two function templates is more specialized than the other **by transforming each template in turn** (see next paragraph) and performing template argument deduction using the function type. The deduction process determines whether one of the templates is more specialized than the other. If so, the more specialized template is the one chosen by the partial ordering process. If both deductions succeed, the partial ordering selects the more constrained template (if one exists) as determined below.
> 3. To produce the transformed template, for each type, non-type, or template template parameter (including template parameter packs thereof) synthesize a unique type, value, or class template respectively and substitute it for each occurrence of that parameter in the function type of the template. ...
> 4. Using the transformed function template's function type, perform type deduction against the other template as described in [temp.deduct.partial].

Transformed template of `f(X<T>)` is `f(X<U1>)` and of `f(X<Ts...>)` is `f(X<U2FromPack>)`, where `U1` and `U2FromPack` are two synthesized unique types. Now, [temp.deduct.partial#2-4,8,10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.partial#2) says:

> 2. Two sets of types are used to determine the partial ordering. For each of the templates involved there is the original function type and the transformed function type.
>    [Note 1: The creation of the transformed type is described in [temp.func.order]. — end note]
>    **The deduction process uses the transformed type as the argument template and the original type of the other template as the parameter template. This process is done twice for each type involved in the partial ordering comparison: once using the transformed template-1 as the argument template and template-2 as the parameter template and again using the transformed template-2 as the argument template and template-1 as the parameter template.**
> 3. The types used to determine the ordering depend on the context in which the partial ordering is done:
>
>    - (3.1) In the context of a function call, the types used are those function parameter types for which the function call has arguments.130
>    - (3.2) In the context of a call to a conversion function, the return types of the conversion function templates are used.
>    - (3.3) **In other contexts the function template's function type is used**.
> 4. Each type nominated above from the parameter template and the corresponding type from the argument template are used as the types of P and A.

> 8. Using the resulting types P and A, the deduction is then done as described in [temp.deduct.type]. ... **If deduction succeeds for a given type, the type from the argument template is considered to be at least as specialized as the type from the parameter template.**

> 10. **Function template F is at least as specialized as function template G if, for each pair of types used to determine the ordering, the type from F is at least as specialized as the type from G.** F is more specialized than G if F is at least as specialized as G and G is not at least as specialized as F.

Now, in our case, per 3.3, the function type itself is the only one considered among types to determine ordering. So, per 2, 8 and 10, to know whether `f(X<T>)` is at least as specialized as `f(X<Ts...>)` we need to see whether `void(X<T>)` is at least as specialized as `void(X<Ts...>)`, or, equivalently, whether *deduction from type* for P=`void(X<Ts...>)` from A=`void(X<U1>)` succeeds. It does according to [temp.deduct.type#9-10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type#9):

> 9. If P has a form that contains <T> or <i>, then each argument P<sub>i</sub>
>    of the respective template argument list of P is compared with the corresponding argument A<sub>i</sub> of the corresponding template argument list of A. If the template argument list of P contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument, the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context. **If P<sub>i</sub> is a pack expansion, then the pattern of P<sub>i</sub> is compared with each remaining argument in the template argument list of A. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by P<sub>i</sub>.** ...
> 10. Similarly, if P has a form that contains (T), then each parameter type P<sub>i</sub> of the respective parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) of P is compared with the corresponding parameter type A<sub>i</sub> of the corresponding parameter-type-list of A. ...

Here, per 10, comparison of functions types results in a single comparison of `X<Ts...>` and `X<U1>`, which, according to 9, succeeds.

Thus, deduction is succesful, so `f(X<T>)` is indeed at least as specialized as `f(X<Ts...>)`, so `std::variant` matches `template<typename> typename V`. Intuitively, we gave 'more general' template template argument which should work nicely for intended usage of a more specific template template parameter.

In practice, different compilers enable P0522R0 changes under different circumstances, and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) template parameters page (section *Template template arguments*) contains links and information on GCC, Cland and MSVC. In particular, GCC in C++17+ mode enables it by default (and for previous standards with compiler flag `fnew-ttp-matching`), but Clang doesn't in any mode unless `-frelaxed-template-template-args` flag is provided, thus you got the difference in output for them. With the flag, Clang also produces correct behaviour ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3eb9qPv4Y)).